# PHP Fusing two arrays

Tags: php

How to connect 2 arrays? I want that `$new[$code]=$color`, how can I do this? Below is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT user_id, user_color FROM dotp_users";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$code = $color = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $code[] = $row['user_id'];
        $color[] = $row['user_color'];
}
```

Comment: Declare the variable `$new = array();`, then inside while loop `$new[$row['user_id']] = $row['user_color']`

Comment: In the while loop or later? In while `$new[$row['user_id']] = $row['user_color'];`. Otherwise http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php,

Comment: thanx guys! write in answer so i can sign it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the variable outside the while loop

```
$new = array();
```

Then inside while loop

```
$new[$row['user_id']] = $row['user_color'];
```

Answer (score 1):

In the while loop...

```
$sql = "SELECT user_id, user_color FROM dotp_users";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$code = $color = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $new[$row['user_id']] = $row['user_color'];
}
```

If you need the arrays seperate for some reason you can do it later using array_combine, http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php.

```
$sql = "SELECT user_id, user_color FROM dotp_users";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$code = $color = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $code[] = $row['user_id'];
        $color[] = $row['user_color'];
}
...
$new = array_combine($code, $color);
```